# Returning interfaces from methods

Tags: vala

In Vala programming language is there a way to declare an interface method that returns an object implementing an interface? For example, if I need a method that reads something from somewhere, I declare it like this:

```vala
interface SeekableInput: GLib.InputStream, GLib.Seekable {}

interface Reader {
  SeekableInput read();
}
```

And now I want to implement a Reader that just reads from memory into MemoryInputStream, which is actually an InputStream implementing Seekable according to its documentation.

```vala
class MemoryReader: Reader {
  GLib.MemoryInputStream _stream;

  // This produces "... overriding method ... is incompatible ... expected return type ...":
  GLib.MemoryInputStream read() { return _stream; }

  // This produces "Cannot convert from ...":
  SeekableInput read() { return _stream; }
}
```

I can't declare `read()` to return `MemoryInputStream` because there would be another `Reader` reading into `BufferedInputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

It's called casting. Something like this should work:

```cs
class MemoryReader: Reader {
  GLib.MemoryInputStream _stream;

  SeekableInput read() { return (SeekableInput)_stream; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's correct? Because MemoryInputStream doesn't actually implement my SeekableInput and I don't know how much legitimate this cast would be.

Comment: According to [MemoryInputStream dcoumentation](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.MemoryInputStream.html) on Valadoc.org it implements both InputStream and Seekable, which is what your SeekableInput interface requires. I've not written a test program to demonstrate that, that's why a [MCVE (Minimal Complete Verfifiable Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you need here a wrapper for your GLib.MemoryInputStream to compile without errors:

```
interface SeekableInput: GLib.InputStream, GLib.Seekable {}

interface Reader {
    SeekableInput read();
}

class MemorySeekableInput: SeekableInput {
    private GLib.MemoryInputStream stream;

    public MemorySeekableInput(GLib.MemoryInputStream stream){
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    // ... implement all abstract methods for InputStream and Seekable
}

class MemoryReader: Reader {
    GLib.MemoryInputStream _stream;

  SeekableInput read() { return new MemorySeekableInput(_stream); }
}
```

your code won't compile, because SeekableInput is a new unique type and it is not equal to GLib.MemoryInputStream type, even if it implements InputStream and Seekable